# Converting a void Algorithm to an int []

Tags: java, arrays, optimization

So I have a program that will find the prime factorization of a number.

```java
public static void primeFactors(int number){
    int i=2;
    while(number>1){
        if (number%i==0){
        System.out.println(i);

            number/=i ;
        }else{
            i++;
            if(isPrime(i)==true){
                        System.out.println(i);

                number/=i;
            }else{
                i++;
}}}}
```

But the thing is I want it to return as an Array. And It has to be able to take a large number and run within 5 seconds. So I converted the working algorithm to this:

```java
public static int[] primeFactors2(int number){
    int[] arrayINT =new int[10];
    int i = 2;
    int index=0;
    while(i<=number/2){
        if(number %i==0 && isPrime(i)){
           arrayINT[index]=i;
           index++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return arrayINT;
}}
```

And this doesn't return the right result, and isn't efficient speed wise. What the heck am I doing wrong!

And here is isPrime():

```java
     public static boolean isPrime(int number){
                if (number<2){
                        return false;
                }
                if (number==2){
                        return true;
                }
                if (number%2==0){
                        return false;
                }
                int ceiling=number; 
                for(int i=3;number>i&&ceiling>i;i+=2){   
                        if(number%i==0){
                                return false;
                        }
                        ceiling=number/i;   
              }  return true;
        }
```

Comment: can you share `isPrime`?

Comment: Just edited it!

Comment: I'd be inclined to guess that the second version doesn't even *compile*, as a result of an extra closing brace (`}`) at `i++;}`.  If it does compile then it probably doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes it does, it's not an extra closing brace. Please see the void one above it, (which works beautifully) it has the same

Comment: It seems to have a logical issue as well. When I invoke `primeFactors(10)`, it prints 2 and 3. Is this correct? I believe the answer should be 2 and 5.

Comment: The first version *does not* have the same.  The corresponding `i++;` has four closing braces following it, whereas the second has five (with a `return` statement in between), even though the two codes seem intended to parallel each other.  At absolute minimum, the second example's formatting is extremely misleading.

Comment: @PavanKumar Hmmm!!! yes you're right :( I didn't notice with the large tests I was using

Comment: Additionally, although `isPrime()` isn't too bad for performing *one* primality test, using it to perform multiple primality tests involves a great many duplicate computations.  I'd suggest using a prime number sieve, once, to generate a list of primes up to `number`, and then iterating over the elements of that list to factor the number.  Or even to integrate the factoring with the sieving.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Mate, they are identical in the sense that i converted the void to return an array. Obviously it's not the exact same. It's the int[] version of it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks, but we can't according to constraits. This is a snippit from a larger project.

Comment: How do you measure quantitatively speed of an algorithm? @PhilpAdoni

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code a bit to accommodate your requirement. Please take a look.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
```

--

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    primeFactors(630);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(primeFactors2(630)));

}

public static void primeFactors(int number) {
    int i = 2;
    int init = number;
    while(i<=init/2){
        if(number %i==0 && isPrime(i)){
            System.out.println(i);
            number/=i;
            i--;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

public static Integer[] primeFactors2(int number) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = 2;
    int init = number;
    while(i<=init/2){
        if(number %i==0 && isPrime(i)){
            list.add(i);
            number/=i;
            i--;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
}

public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    if (number < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    if (number == 2) {
        return true;
    }
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    int ceiling = number;
    for (int i = 3; number > i && ceiling > i; i += 2) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        ceiling = number / i;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Edited to add imports. We cannot initialize an array to store results as we do not know in advance on how many factors would exist. Thus, we use `List` to capture the values and convert the same to array. I would actually recommend you to use `List` as a return type instead. If you find the solution satisfactory, you can please accept the answer so that others are aware that the issue is resolved.

Comment: What is the issue faced?

Comment: please look at my edited version of primeFactors2. it does not return right input it appears

Comment: in fact your primefactors gives incorrect output as well my friend. for example try 630 or 121@Pavan Kumar

Comment: ok, I got your logic. Earlier I was just printing the factors, now the output should be as you expect... It matches with the output here: http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/prime-factors.php